# OAuth 2.0 Token type alias in Android for Google Calendar

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, oauth-2.0

I'm developing an Android application which uses the AccountManager to get access to the User's Google Calendar. I'm using the Java Calendar API version 3. I have a working sample however the Authorization token type I use to obtain permission from the user is not human readable, currently I use:

```
    private static final String AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";
```

So I'm trying to find a human readable token type as this doesn't give the user a good indication of what permission they are giving to the application. There is an alias for Google Tasks as detailed [in this blog post](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-google-tasks-api-and-oauth-20-on.html) - 'Manage your tasks' is used. Is there a similar alias for Google Calendar on Android?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?  I'm trying to find an alias for Google Docs.

Comment: No - only alias I've found is for Google Tasks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "Manage your calendars" if you want to view and manage the user's calendar. Otherwise use the less powerful "View your calendars" which gives you read-only access.